# Which term is ‘Elyon’ derived from and what is its significance?

Tags: genesis, hebrew, word-study

Genesis 14:18

> And Melchizedek king of Salem brought out bread and wine; now he was a priest of God Most High.

The ‘Most High’ translates the Hebrew adjective ‘Elyon’. What is the term which ‘Elyon’ is derived from and what is its significance?

Answer (score 3):

The operative word in Gen 14:18 (its first occurrence in the OT) is **עֶלְיוֹן (elyown)**.  Its fundamental meaning is:

> high, upper (BDB); Most high, uppermost (Strong's)

According to Strong's concordance, the word derives from **עָלָה (alah)** a verb meaning:

> to go up, ascend, climb (Strong's)

The word עֶלְיוֹן (elyown) is used in two senses in the OT:

1. **of earthly things and people** such as

- "upper Beth-Horon", Josh 16:5, 1 Chron 7:24, 2 Chron 8:5
- "upper basket", Gen 40:17
- "upper pool", 2 Kings 18:17, Isa 26:2
- "upper chamber", Eze 41:7, 42:5
- Israel to be a superior nation, Deut 26:19, 28:1
- "upper gate", 2 Kings 15:35, 2 Chron 23:20, 27:3
- "upper outlet" (of water), 2 Chron 32:20

2. **title of God as supreme = "Most High"**

- eg, Gen 14:18, 19, 20, 22, Num 24;16, Deut 32:8, 2 Sam 22:14, Ps 7:17, etc.

Note that in the latter case, the word is used as a title of God as supreme, either:

- alone as simply, "The Most High", eg, Num 24:15, Deut 32:8, 2 Sam 22;14, Ps 9:2, 18:13, 21:17, 46:4, Isa 14:14, etc
- in conjunction with the word "el" or "elohim" and thus, "God Most High", eg, Gen 14:18, 19, 20, 22, Ps 57:2, 78:35, etc
- in conjunction with LORD (YHWH) and thus, "The LORD Most High", Ps 7:17, 47:2, 97:9, etc.

Comment: Incidentally, Jews who move from their native countries to Israel are said to ['make Aliyah](https://www.jewishagency.org/aliyah/)' meaning to "go up." Throughout the OT one would "go up" to Jerusalem and "go down" from there to other places. The term carries a spiritual connotation as well as a physical one.

Comment: @DanFefferman - quite right, although "alah" is the verb (eg, Isa 38:22) and this question is discussing the adjective whose cognate root is the verb.

Answer (score 0):

Although English texts usually say "God Most High" some give the more literal rendering of *El Elyon*. The name *el* means "god/God" but it was also the name of a specific Canaanite deity, [the father of the gods](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/El). In Canaanite texts, "most high" (*elyon/aliyan* etc.) was an honorific epithet for both El and Baal. For example in [the following Ugaritic text](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Baal) the title of Most High is given to Baal:

> Baal sets the season, and gives forth His voice from the clouds. He
> flashes lightning to the earth. As a house of cedars let Him complete
> it, Or a house of bricks let Him erect it! Let it be told to **Aliyan
> Baal**: 'The mountains will bring Thee much silver. The hills, the
> choicest of gold; The mines will bring Thee precious stones, And build
> a house of silver and gold. A house of lapis gems!'

In the case of Melchizedek, the deity was [El](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/El), to whom the honorific epithet "most high" (עֶלְי֔וֹן) was affixed. Whether Melchizedek worshiped him as the only God (as Abraham did) or as the highest of many gods is a [matter of debate](https://www.thoughtstheological.com/melchizedek-abraham-muslims-and-worship-of-the-one-true-god/). However the Semitic term "most high" was used for other deities in Canaanite culture, prior to its application to the LORD in Israelite religion.